# Sharepoint 2010: Variations

Tags: variations

There is a good [article](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2008/04/fun-with-variations/) on the Variations (for 2007).

I have some questions:

1) I have already created structure of portal (nodes, lists, pages, etc.). I want to introduce a multi-lingual on site. Why when I configure the Variations for existing content does not cover? A newly added distributed.

Before:

- Site

  - Web1

    - List1
  - Web2

    - List2

After:

- Site

  - Web1

    - List1
  - Web2

    - List2
  - Variation 1
  - Variation 2

2) How to make Variation 1 - this was the existing structure of the site. And it dubbed Variation 2? It is clear that if I add something to Variation 1, it is added to Variation 2.

3) What data is duplicated in the options? Lists, field, list items, registered event receivers?

4) How to make Variation 1 begins with the first level of the hierarchy?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please try to ask **only one** question in a question. This is the best fit for our system and means your posts will be easier to answer and find in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx#limitations
Variation feature copies ONLY Pages library and optionaly it's elements (such images).
From structure variation synchronize only subsite, not lists.

> Variations for existing content does not cover?

No. To pages library of variation root site will be added special page, that become home. It will be redirect to specific variation (for example to the Spanish variation).

All variation will be empty, it isn't use content of exeting page.

Comment: it be helpfull to discover other msdn articles about variation